# How to write Coordinate Chart in Xcoba in index form?

Tags: packages, tensors

I am using [xCoba](http://www.xact.es/) for manipulating tensors. I do the usual, defining my metric, manifold, chart etc.

```
DefManifold[M4, 4, {a, b, c, d, e, f}]
DefChart[B4, M4, {0, 1, 2, 3}, {x0[], t[], x[], y[]}]
DefBasis[cartesian4, TangentM4, {0, 1, 2, 3}, BasisColor -> RGBColor[0, 0, 1]]
DefMetric[-1, g[-a, -b], CD, PrintAs -> "g"]
```

Now I define a symmetric tensor J by

```
DefTensor[J[-a, -b], M4, Symmetric[{-a, -b}]]
```

Now I want to replace `J_ab` by `x_a x_b` where `x_a` is  the coordinate vector i.e. the components of `x_a` are `{x0[], t[], x[], y[]}`. But I can't write `J_ab` in this index form.

I have looked through the documentation, and I haven't found how I can do this.

Any idea how to replace `J_ab` by `x_a x_b`?